# How to fix the date to be in the bottom and in the line of the text dependant of the text?

Tags: html, css

I designed a message to have the date in the bottom.

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9y1b80wu/1/)

I don't know how to make the date to be in the bottom (For example the second box).
And I don't know how to fix the date to be in the line of the text, if the text is not too long. (For example the first box)

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: pink;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: right;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt 
  </div>
  HH:MM
</div>
<br/>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    txt txt txt txt txt txt <br>
    txt txt txt txt txt txt
  </div>
  HH:MM
</div>
```

I appreciate every help :)

Comment: Will `HH:MM` will always be below `txt txt` text or in the line of it when `txt txt` is small?

Comment: It should be inline with if it's small @m4n0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to youe code.
In this way you can show the date right bottom.

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: pink;
  width: 70%;
}

.child {
  text-align: left;
}

.right{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  <span>
    txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt txt
    </span>
    <span class="right"> HH:MM</span>
  </div>
 
</div>
<br/>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  <span>
    txt txt txt txt txt txttxt <br /> txt txt txt txt txt
    </span>
    <span class="right">HH:MM</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I have another question, is it possible to have this design when the content of the child element is an [innerHTML] ? I tried a lot but it always have some problems.

Answer (score -2):

You can set a class name for the date like this :

```
<span class="className"> HH:MM </span>
```

Then you can adjust it's position by setting margin or padding to the class name like this :

```
.className {
   // Setting margin 
   margin-top : 10px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   // Or padding
   padding-top : 10px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. But the problem is I don't know how much is the text. It is an input and users may enter different amounts of text. Maybe I should have mentioned it. Thanks BTW.

Comment: @MinaS You can use position absolute to the span and position relative to the whole div and then position the span so it will always be on that position no matter the text size